# Primefaces component display issue

Tags: java, css, primefaces

Primefaces version: 3.5

I am not able to get the two components in the following code into one line.
The p:inputText is always displayed some pixels lower than the p:selectOneMenu.
This problem is not caused by different margin. Setting a margin does not help.
I have tried this with different themes, but the problem is always the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectOneMenu>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Test"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Test 2"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:inputText />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Is there any way to get the components display in one line?

Comment: Try using the css properties to allign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by setting the vertical-align of the input component.

```
<p:inputText style="vertical-align: top;" />
```